# eap-peap x eap-tls - cerfiticate freeradius authentication

Tags: certificate, private-key, ca, freeradius

I have a client that manages its network and internet link. Today we do security through MAC ADDRESS blocking which generates a lot of wear and tear. The company's machines have their own certificate installed and they asked for a solution so that machines with such a certificate are validated by a server and can use the WIFI and wired network.

Turns out the company can only provide me with the .crt certificate and the rootCA.crt and doesn't have access to the private key.

And they insist that only with these 02 files can I validate the users.

Another difficulty in generating a specific certificate for this would be the difficulty imposed by their security team in installing third-party certificates on all machines.

In a last email I was told:

"I talked to the Central team and they assured me that you won't need the private key....they were in line with what I thought from the beginning....you must have the root and intermediate CA on your server. When the notebook to connect to the network you validate the local certificate, signed by the intermediate CA and by the Root.... if everything is ok you can trust and allow the connection to the network. What will happen is that we will not know if that certificate was “disabled” because the revocation list cannot be accessed."

Can you help me in any way?

I TRIED USE THIS CERTIFICATES, BUT I REALLY NEED THE PRIVATE KEY ?

a solution for this problem

Comment: It's not clear what part of this project you're doing. The client needs the private key to sign things, but verification doesn't use the private key.

Comment: only has the CA and public key, can I validate the users who have these files on their machine without access to the private key .key?